# regex numeros o numeros con guión

Tags: regex

Lo que intento hacer es que me devuelva verdadero si insertan valores (formulario en php) de 3 a 4 cifras o dos números separados por un guion de 3 a 4 cifras, por lo contrario devuelva falso.

```
^(\d{3,4}-{1}){1}\d{3,4}$
```

Comment: Explica un poco mejor qué es lo que quieres lograr. Está un poco confusa la pregunta.

Comment: Lo leí varias veces y no me queda claro si solo debería ser de 3 cifras (ni más ni menos), o si podrían ser más. No tiene lógica con tu descripción que hayas intentado con `{1,4}`. Además, como se pide en [la descripción de la etiqueta regex](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info), tendrías que especificar **en qué lenguaje** estás trabajando, diferentes ejemplos de texto contra el cual intenta que coincidan, el resultado esperado (¿es sólo para devolver verdadero/falso, o se va a usar para otra cosa?), y casos en los cuales no debería coincidir.

Comment: Los `{1}` sólo sirven para complicar el regex y hacerlo menos legible; no necesitas indicar cardinalidad para cada elemento, ya que por defecto es `1`.

Comment: Puede ser con un grupo opcional: ( )? ^\d{1,4}(-\d{1,4})?$

Comment: Hola, perdón por no aclarar la pregunta. Lo que intento hacer es que me devuelva verdadero si insertan  valores (formulario en php) de 3 a 4 cifras o dos números separados por un guion de 3 a 4 cifras, por lo contrario devuelva falso. Me equivoque en poner {1,4}, realmente era {3,4}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Números de únicamente entre 3 y 4 dígitos
- Dos números de únicamente entre 3 y 4 dígitos separados por un guión

Eso lo puedes lograr con:

```
 ^[0-9]{3,4}(-[0-9]{3,4})?$
```

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/V30PlazUYnqFI3xq)

- `^` inicio del texto
- `[0-9]{3,4}` únicamente números de entre 3 y 4 dígitos
- `(-[0-9]{3,4})?` un guión separado por únicamente 3 o 4 numeros, por lo cual no evaluaría a true cuando se ingresan valores como `450-`. A su vez este grupo es opcional permitiendo valores como `350`
- `$` fin del texto

Comment: ¿Qué sentido tiene responder antes de que el autor de la pregunta siquiera especifique el lenguaje y aclare la pregunta? Además, la primera expresión coincide con textos que tienen más que 3 dígitos

Comment: Que este claro o no es subjetivo, tomo igual tu consejo, pero me pareció que estaba la información disponible para elaborar una respuesta. Podrías darme un ejemplo de textos con mas de 3 dígitos que coincidan para la primera expresión?

Comment: Es cierto, es subjetiva la interpretación, pero no los puntos que le fata cubrir a la pregunta (ver https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info). Por ejemplo, tu expresión fallaría en algunos lenguajes ([BRE](http://www.regular-expressions.info/gnu.html#bre)). Tus expresiones coinciden con cualquier inicio de texto, ya que te faltó utilizar `^` (o `\A`, dependiendo del lenguaje).

Comment: Es verdad, gracias. En cuanto OP brinde mas información actualizo la respuesta.

Comment: Hola, perdón por no aclarar la pregunta. Lo que intento hacer es que me devuelva verdadero si insertan  valores (formulario en php) de 3 a 4 cifras o dos números separados por un guion de 3 a 4 cifras, por lo contrario devuelva falso.

Comment: He actualizado la respuesta según tu comentario. Sugiero que edites tu pregunta con la aclaración.